# error: cannot find symbol @MicronautTest()

Tags: kotlin, micronaut, kotest

Kotest 4 was removed from Micronaut 4 ([ref](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/8075)) so I follow this guide to install Kotest 5:

https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/snapshot/guide/index.html#settingUpKoTest5

However, after running the test using `./gradlew test` I got this error.

```
error: cannot find symbol @MicronautTest()
```

**MyTest.kt**

```
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.kotest5.annotation.MicronautTest
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.AnnotationSpec

@MicronautTest
class MyTest : AnnotationSpec() {
    @Test
    fun testMyFunc() {
       ...
    }
}
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
dependencies {
    kaptTest ("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-kotest5:4.2.0")
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.13.9")
    testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-runner-junit5-jvm:5.8")
}

tasks.withType<Test>().configureEach {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

micronaut {
    ...
    testRuntime("kotest5")
    ...
}
```

**ProjectConfig.kt**

```
import io.kotest.core.config.AbstractProjectConfig
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.kotest5.MicronautKotest5Extension

@Suppress("unused")
object ProjectConfig : AbstractProjectConfig() {
    override fun extensions() = listOf(MicronautKotest5Extension)
}
```

- Micronaut version: 4.2.1
- Kotlin version: 1.9.10